# Moving the mouse cursor asynchronous

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know if there is any way to move the cursor without locking the UI thread in Winforms. In other words; an async solution.

My current synchronous solution:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan delayt = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
    LinearSmoothMove(new Point(20, 40), delayt);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

public static void LinearSmoothMove(Point newPosition, TimeSpan duration)
{
    Point start = Cursor.Position;
    int sleep = 10;

    double deltaX = newPosition.X - start.X;
    double deltaY = newPosition.Y - start.Y;

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    double timeFraction = 0.0;
    do
    {
        timeFraction = (double)stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks / duration.Ticks;
        if (timeFraction > 1.0)
            timeFraction = 1.0;
        PointF curPoint = new PointF((float)(start.X + timeFraction * deltaX), 
                                    (float)(start.Y + timeFraction * deltaY));
        SetCursorPos(Point.Round(curPoint).X, Point.Round(curPoint).Y);
        Thread.Sleep(sleep);
    } while (timeFraction < 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Using `Timer`? (At least it's the simplest one)

Comment: @KingKing Yea, I was hoping for another alternative

Comment: At least it's better than the current solution of yours.

Comment: Why can't you use a Thread if a Timer isn't preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `BackgroundWorker` as romano said, but for that little function you can just use a timer:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
   timer.Interval = 10;
   timer.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
   timer.Start();
}

  void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // Your code
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Thread or a `BackgroundWorker` like this:

```
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.DoWork += (s, ex) =>
            {
                SetCursorPos(0, 0);
            };

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: As far as I know, `BackgroundWorker` doesn't do the work periodically, to make it work that way, you have to call `Thread.Sleep(...)`? It's not suitable for the OP's problem.

Comment: You're right. I got his problem wrong. I thought he really needs to do this outside the UI thread.